# Множественный маппинг url для REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, servlet

Работаю над приложением, у которого все url идут с адресом "/someurl.htm". Если я меняю в @RequestMapping на "/someurl", то браузер все равно перекидывает на .htm.
Ситуация осложняется тем, что в приложении уже есть несколько перехватчиков в web.xml:
Этот периодически проверяет наличие лицензии у пользователя.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ru.someTh.AllRequestsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Следующий перенаправляет на страницу логина (login.jsp)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>loginredirection</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ru.smTh.security.LoginRedirectionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginredirection</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Еще один (springservlet.xml) перенаправляет на странице активации, если лицензии нет.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/*"/>
        <bean id="loginInterceptor"
              class="ru.someClass">
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

DispatcherServlet (при попытке изменить *.htm все летит)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Я пробовала решить проблему несколькими способами:

- Сделала bean mapping с указанием url и класса контроллера.
- Написала Filter с проверкой URI
- Написала сервлет:

  ```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>teachersList</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/api/teachers</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   List<Teacher> teacherList = referenceDao.loadTeachers();

   String json = new Gson().toJson(teacherList);
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.getWriter().write(json);}
  ```

Последний вариант был самым "успешным" - приложение выдало ошибку null, до этого вообще никак не реагировало.

**В принципе хотелось бы узнать, как сохранив старые jsp и .htm ввернуть в код url для JSON, минуя авторизацию и проверку лицензий**

Comment: Слишком мало информации для диагностики. Ты говоришь про множество фильтров, но непонятно что в них. Если ты хочешь исключить url из фильтра, то просто поправь его `mapping` в web.xml. Или измени сам код фильтра, чтобы он стал "умно" фильтровать запросы. Почему всегда htm? Опять не хватает информации: каковы дефолтные страницы и вообще какова настройка. Расширь вопрос, чтобы тебе смогли помочь.